# How to prevent executing php onclick function without clicking with smarty

Tags: onclick, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need some help with a template on prestashop. What i'm trying to achieve is that when the customer clicks on a link, it should call a php function from my model that adds a product to the cart.

But it seems that the function is executed whether the link is clicked or not. As soon as the link is "readed" (by Smarty i guess) it is executed. How can i prevent that and only execute the function when the link is clicked?

Here below you can find my template's code.

Thanks in advance

```
<div class="bloc_bouton_recap">
  <h4>Ce produit ne vous convient pas et vous souhaitez reprendre la configuration à zero? <a href="{$link->getModuleLink('formulairemodule')}" name="lien_config" title="Configurateur">Suivez ce lien</a></h4>
  <h3>nbproduxcts : {$cart->nbProducts()}</h3>

</div>
  <div class="bloc_bouton_recap">
    <h4>Ajouter ce produit à <a href="{$link->getModuleLink('formulairemodule')}" class="lien_panier" onclick='{Formulaire::addProduitAuPanier($idproduct)}' >votre panier</a></h4>
    <h3>nbproduxcts : {$cart->nbProducts()}</h3>
</div>
```

The h3 tags are only here to display the quantity of products in my cart and the last one always display 1 more than the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place in onclick Javascript function and not PHP/Smarty call.

In Javascript function you should then for example using AJAX launch url where there's a script that adds a product to the cart.

You need to learn about Javascript/AJAX if you want to achieve that. Using only Smarty and PHP you won't be able to do this.

Comment: Thanks i read 2 minutes ago that smarty actually executes code before displaying it so i'll work with ajax then.